# Performing an action on idle state in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timeout, python-idle, mousemove

I'm trying to set up a script in a webpage that does the following: if the mouse is inactive for a certain amount of time (say, five seconds), perform an action (say, hiding an element); then, if the mouse of moved, perform an action (say, un-hiding the element).

What I want is some way to perform an action on user mouse inactivity (not necessarily keyboard inactivity).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jQuery:

```
(function() {
    var timeout;
    var isHidden = false;
    $(document).mousemove(function() {
        if (timeout) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (!isHidden) {
                //hide the element here
                isHidden = true;
            }
        }, 5000);
        if (isHidden) {
            //show the element here
            isHidden = false;
        }
    });
})();
```

Non jQuery version:

```
(function() {
    var timeout;
    var isHidden = false;

    function hideOnIdle() {
        if (timeout) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (!isHidden) {
                //hide the element here
                isHidden = true;
            }
        }, 5000);
        if (isHidden) {
            //show the element here
            isHidden = false;
        }
    }

    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", hideOnIdle);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent("onmousemove", hideOnIdle);
    }
})();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PHQMS/)

Comment: I'm using normal JavaScript. I've had a go at converting it, but I can't get it to work. I've put it up here: http://jsfiddle.net/LGdWL/2/

Comment: This should all be wrapped in an anonymous function to prevent pollution of the global scope.

Comment: Why not use `setInterval` and be done with the clear/set timeout stuff?

Comment: You will still have to reset it when the user moves the mouse, so I doubt it will help.